# How to perform error handling for 200 functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-catch, python-decorators

Following is a sample function

```
def temp(data):
    a = sample_function_1(data)
    a = a[0][0]
    b = sample_function_2(data,'no',0,30)
    b = b[-1]
    c = sample_function_3(data, 'thank', 0, None, 15, 5)
    c = c[-2]
    print(a, b, c)
    return a, b, c
```

Error handling is done for `sample_function_1`, `sample_function_2`, and `sample_function_3` . So the values returned by these functions cause no problem but the calculations done on the variables `a, b, c` can throw errors.

There are more than 200 functions like this and I need to manage the errors effectively. I know that try, catch, except is an option but are there any approaches that can be taken to solve this problem.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is the whole structure of the application. If you have more than 200 functions, all apparently with slightly different interfaces, that's going to be totally unreadable. Could you give some more context? This seems like an XY problem right now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe These 200 functions are similar to the function above with some minor changes in between. Basically, I'm working with strings and every function solves a specific task for a particular company. Does this work?

Comment: What "minor changes"? What "strings"? What "specific task" and "particular company"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am performing text mining on invoices of different stores. The format is different for different stores. The sample_functions are util functions that solve common tasks. The variables a,b,c need some additional processing on the values returned from sample_functions. I am able to handle errors from sample_functions because they are common but the problem that I am facing is handling errors for variables a,b,c. These variables a,b,c are common throughout 200 functions and I have no idea about how to handle errors. Does this make things clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 200 functions to change everything is going to be some hard work but you could try to use a decorator, you will only be able to intercept one error per function but it may be a good compromise for your case.

```
def exception_logger(func):
    wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
           ...doSomething...
           raise
    return wrapper

@exception_logger
def temp(data):
   ...doSomething...
```

Comment: This is a good idea but it intercepts only one error. Is there any way to handle a maximum of 3 errors per function. I just want to return np.NaN from the exception logger that's it

Comment: @DhavalThakkar I'm not sure what you mean by only one error. If any of your calculation raise an error it will catch it and you can return `np.nan` from the decorator. It wont execute your function further hence not raise any more exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just define a function and just call the exception_logger function in any of your except block in any function.

```
import traceback

def exception_logger():
    exception_log = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
    exception_log.append(str(datetime.now()))
    print exception_log
    return exception_log

def hello():
    try:
        print("Hello World!")

    except Exception as e:
        exception_logger()
```

Comment: I have 200 functions like the hello function you've mentioned. Also, I have 3 variables a,b,c and writing try except for all the 3 variables and 200 functions will be too much manual work